# Should I mock Repository and Unit Of Work for Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, repository, mocking, unit-of-work

I have read this article: https://www.gaui.is/how-to-mock-the-datacontext-linq/

Since this article is almost 4 years old I have no hope that in article's comments my question will be answered so I decided to ask it here.

In this article author creates another `MockRepository` and `MockUnitOfWork` classes and implements their own methods to match `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` methods. but uses List instead of `DataContext`.

If I use this approach, and in future I will change my implementation for `Repository` or `UnitOfWork`. It means that I have to change Implementation for `MockRepository` and `MockUnitOfWork` too.

It seems a bit frustarting for me. It looks like I am testing `MockRepository` and `MockUnitOfWork` separately and `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` still stays untested.

How do you think?

Comment: You mixed up some things. You want to test `code X`. `Code X` depends on `item Y`. Now you mock `item Y` in your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the pattern described in the article, then you would only need to change `MockRepository` or `MockUnitOfWork` if the respective interface (`IRepository` and `IUnitOfWork`) changes.

The idea behind this is that you can unit-test all the other parts of your application without needing access to a real database (and without the trouble that data persistence in a proper database gives you while testing).

Only the `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` classes themselves (the ones that contain the actual database connection) would need a real database to be unit-tested and if their implementation is simple enough, you can even choose to defer testing of those classes till the integration or end-to-end tests.

Comment: Nice answer. I got the point now. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The author is using a LINQ to SQL `DataContext` which is not that simple to mock. There are ways to mock it but you can simply go around that and create a fake implementation of a `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` to use in your tests. If you go the extra mile and create a viable mock for a `DataContext` then you shouldn't create mocks for your `Repository` and `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: Yes, as it seems if I want to unit-test Repository or UnitOfWork I have to mock DataContext, right?

Comment: In that case, yes. I assume the author didn't unit test his implementations otherwise we would have seen a mock for the `DataContext`. If your repository is only forwarding calls to the context you probably don't have to unit test it.

Comment: Let's say I have simple method in my repository like this: 
public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T,bool>> pred)
{
    return pred!=null?context.FirstorDefault(pred):context.FirstOrDefault();
} 
should I unit-test this?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do so.